# Find the greatest integer less than or equal to $(\sqrt 2 + 1)^6$

Tags: combinatorics

The greatest integer less than or equal to $(\sqrt 2  + 1)^7$ is _____.

I have solved the same for finding the greatest integer less than or equal to $(\sqrt 2  + 1)^6$ and my detailed solution is elaborated below

[image]

Can we find the same when power is 7 if so then how do we do that.

Comment: Hint: as the solution shows, $(\sqrt 2 +1)^n+(-\sqrt 2 +1)^n$ is an integer, and $(-\sqrt 2 +1)^n$ has absolute value less than $1$.  Also, let $a_n=(\sqrt 2 +1)^n+(-\sqrt 2 +1)^n$ we have $a_0=2,a_1=2$ and $a_{n+1}=2a_n+a_{n-1}$.

Comment: The answer is $478$.

Comment: If the question is about the power of $7,$ why does the title mention the case $6?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach to avoid computing all those binomial coefficients is to use that: $$x_n=(1+\sqrt{2})^n+(1-\sqrt2)^n$$ satisfies $$x_{n+2}=2x_{n+1}+x_n$$ With $x_0=x_1=2.$

And, since $-1<1-\sqrt2<0,$ we get,  for any $n>0,$ $$\left\lfloor (1+\sqrt 2)^n\right\rfloor=\begin{cases}x_n&n\text{ odd}\\x_n-1&n\text{ even}\end{cases}$$

This gives $$x_2=6\\x_3=14\\x_4=34\\x_5=82\\x_6=198\\x_7=478\\\vdots$$

---

Amusingly, since $$\frac{1}{2}1^n+\frac{1}{2}(-1)^n=\begin{cases}1&n\text{ even}\\0&n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$

You can actually get a recurrence for $y_n=\left\lfloor(1+\sqrt 2)^n\right\rfloor$ as: $$y_{n+4}=2y_{n+3}+2y_{n+2}-2y_{n+1}-y_n$$

Comment: if we have $ (5+2\sqrt 6)$ then can you explain me the recursive formula  as you applied in previous problem

Comment: In general, for $y_n=(a+b\sqrt d)^n+(a-b\sqrt d)^n$ you get: $$y_{n+2}=2a y_{n+1}-(a^2-db^2)y_n$$

Comment: In general, you need to know the relation between the linear recurrence $$z_{n+k}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_i z_{n+i}$$ and the roots of the polynomial $$p(x)=z^k-\sum a_i x^i.$$

Comment: Here, $a\pm b\sqrt d$ are the roots of $x^2-2a x+(a^2-db^2)=0.$

Answer (score 2):

$(\sqrt2+1)^7+(1-\sqrt2)^7=2(1^7+\binom72\sqrt2^21^5+\binom74\sqrt2^41^3+\binom76\sqrt2^61^1)=478$, and $-1<(1-\sqrt2)^7<0$.

So the answer is 478.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to add on with same end result but in a simpler manner.

$$
(\sqrt{2}+1)^6=\mathrm{A}
$$
[A] is the greatest integer less than $\mathrm{A}$.

Let $f$ be some unknown fraction.

Hence, we can write $[\mathrm{A}]+\mathrm{f}=\mathrm{A}$.

Now, $(\sqrt{2}-1)<1$
$$
(\sqrt{2}-1)^6<1
$$
Let, $(\sqrt{2}-1)^6$ be denoted by $f_1$.

So, $\quad(\sqrt{2}+1)^6+(\sqrt{2}-1)^6=[\mathrm{A}]+\mathrm{f}+\mathrm{f}_1$
$$
\Rightarrow 2\left({ }^6 \mathrm{C}_0 \cdot(\sqrt{2})^6+{ }^6 \mathrm{C}_2 \cdot(\sqrt{2})^4+{ }^6 \mathrm{C}_6\right)=[\mathrm{A}]+\mathrm{f}+\mathrm{f}_1
$$
$$
\Rightarrow 2(8+60+31)=[\mathrm{A}]+\mathrm{f}+\mathrm{f}_1
$$
$$
\Rightarrow 198=[\mathrm{A}]+\mathrm{f}+\mathrm{f}_1
$$
Now, $0<\mathrm{f}<1$

$0<\mathrm{f}_1<1$

$0<\mathrm{f}+\mathrm{f}_1<2$

But as $198-[\mathrm{A}]=\mathrm{f}+\mathrm{f}_1$, So, $f+\mathrm{f}_1$ has to be an integer.

As, the only integer in $(0,2)$ is 1 , hence $\mathrm{f}+\mathrm{f}_1=1$

[A] = 197

Just like the other answers posted earlier.

Thank you